# Highlighting current link

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have to use only html and javascript. I have created one single page which contains a top navigation links the url for those links are something like:

domain.com, 
domain.com/b1, 
domain.com/b2

how do I highlight the current link.

Comment: `window.location.href` might be a good start.

Comment: pure javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750619/javascript-to-highlight-current-nav-and-sub-directories with jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955851/highlight-current-page-in-jquery

Comment: Hi everybady and thanks for spending your times to answer this question. and sorry about my mistake and poor description of the problem. the problem is I am using SharePoint and a cross site collection top navigation so the urls will be changed dramatically. and I have no access to the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

If I understend question you may try html-attribute style for link tag:

```
<a style="color: red">link</a>
```

OR edit CSS-file for that link.

You can set class with serverside and define this class into CSS.

If coding only JS see for JS-object window.location.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a simple JS script to check the `href` of the link and compare it to the `window.location.href` (the current URL).

Here's a simple example using JQuery:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;

$('a').each(function(index) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    if (url === currentUrl) {
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("current");
    }
});
```

Here it adds a class `current` to the link if it is the current link. I have a demo [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EEARK/15/).

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('highlight');
```

replace pathname by one property (or a combination of properties) of the location object if it's not the good one.

the snippet add 'highlight' class to the link with the specified href, then you can write some css to highlight your link.